# How to pass parameters to caret summary functions

Tags: r, r-caret

How can I pass parameters to caret summary functions?

For instance, the twoClassSummary-function of caret has the following signature:
twoClassSummary(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL)

The parameter lev specificies the factor-level I am interested in.
Now I want to tell caret that I am interested in the summary for the factor level "false". Something like

```
  trainControl(summary=twoClassSummary(lev="false"))
```

does not work. How can I pass parameters to the summary function? Thanks!

Comment: Try to be more specific in describing the problem. Why does it not work? What's the error message? What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333029/specifying-positive-class-of-an-outcome-variable-in-caret-train

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it is currently not possible to do this in a straight-forward manner since additional arguments to train(...) are not passed on to twoClassSummary(). You can use trick to make it work and your idea is pretty close. Create a custom function that passes the values from caret on to the summary function, but works on them or replaces them while doing this.

```
trainControl(
    summaryFunction = function(...) empTwoClassSummary(..., lev = c("your_other_class","false"))
```

You can do the same to pass in additional parameters to a custom summary function, for example:

```
trainControl(
    summaryFunction = function(...) customTwoClassSummary(..., weights = c(0.1, 0.2), orgData = my_data)
```

Unrelated to the question: In your example, make sure that the level you want to be the target level is the second vector element in `lev`, since twoClassSummary() assumes this by default in these lines:

```
lvls <- levels(data$obs)
data$y = as.numeric(data$obs == lev[2])
```